# Find the value of $(1-a_1)(1-a_2)(1-a_3)(1-a_4)$ given that $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ are roots of a biquadratic equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

So the biquadratic equation is $x^4+(2-\sqrt3)x^2+2+\sqrt3=0$. Let $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ be its roots. So we have to find the value of $(1-a_1)(1-a_2)(1-a_3)(1-a_4)$ . 
**My attempt:** 
So of we put $x^2=t$, and let the roots of the new quadratic equation be $a_1,a_2$. So we get that $a_1=-a_3;a_2=-a_4$. So the expression whose value we have to find will become $(1-a_1^2)(1-a_2^2)$. And now we multiply the expression to get, $1-(a_1^2+a_2^2)+(a_1a_2)^2=1-((a_1+a_2)^2-2a_1a_2)+(a_1a_2)^2$. 
Now substituting the values of sum of roots and product of the same, I get the answer $5+10\sqrt3$. But the answer according to my question paper is $5$. 
**So please can someone point out the mistake and tell the answer?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your mistake:

As the new quadratic is a new equation, to avoid confusion I will use $b_1,b_2$ for the roots

$$1-(a_1^2+a_2^2)+(a_1a_2)^2=1-(b_1+b_2)+b_1b_2=1+(2-\sqrt{3})+2+\sqrt{3}
$$

You used $a_1,a_2$ to denote both the original roots and their squares!!!!

Comment: Can you give a reason for why $b_n=a_n^2$

Comment: Ohkk. So we are essentially saying that $a_1^2=a_3^2=b_1^2$?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal Keep the letters. Your original equation is $x^4-...$. Denote the solutions by $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ (these are your $a$'s). After the substitution $t=x^2$ you get the equation $t^2-...$. Call the solutions $t_1,t_2$ (these are the $b's$). Your substitution is $t=x^2$ which means that $t_{1,2} =x_{1,2,3,4}^2$.....

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal Nope. I am saying that if $$a_1^4+(2-\sqrt3)a_1^2+2+\sqrt3=0$$ then $$(a_1)^2+(2-\sqrt3)(a_1^2)+2+\sqrt3=0$$ This makes $a_1^2$ a solution to $$t^2-(2-\sqrt3)t+2+\sqrt3=0$$ If $b_1$ is that solution we get $$b_1=a_1^2$$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:**

Just notice that
$$(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)(x-a_4)=x^4+(2-\sqrt{3})x^2+2+\sqrt{3}$$

---

**About your attempt:**

According to G-man (thanks) we have

\begin{align}
1-(a_1^2+a_2^2)+(a_1a_2)^2&=1-\left(-\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{1}\right)+(2+\sqrt{3})\\
&=1+(2-\sqrt{3})+(2+\sqrt{3})\\
&=5
\end{align}
Where we have used the fact that $(a_1a_2)^2=a_1a_2a_3a_4=2+\sqrt{3}$ from the  Vieta's formulas.

Comment: Ok, intelligence! But can you point out a mistake in my attempt?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal : I don't see how are you finding $a_1+a_2$.

Comment: $a_1+a_2=\frac{-b}a$, where $b,a$ are the Second and leading coefficients respectivEly.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal The roots of the equation you get by substituting $t=x^2$ are not $a_1,a_2$ but $a_1^2,a_2^2$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=1-y$

So, we have $(1-y)^4+(2-\sqrt3)(1-y)^2+2+\sqrt3=0\iff y^4+\cdots+1+(2-\sqrt3)+(2+\sqrt3)=0$

$\implies\prod_{r=1}^4(1-a_r)=(-1)^4\dfrac{1+(2-\sqrt3)+(2+\sqrt3)}1$

Comment: I think I just need the mistake in my attempt. The previous answer is quite simple and ample to answer the question.

Comment: IMHO this is the most natural way of solving this problem. To boot, it works for quartics other than biquadratics. Thanks for saving me the trouble of needing to type it out :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing which are the roots. You have that $$t^2+(2-\sqrt 3)t+(2+\sqrt 3)=0$$

The roots of this equation are $a_1^2$ and $a_2^2$ and you want to find $$(1-a_1^2)(1-a_2^2)=1-(a_1^2+a_2^2)+a_1^2a_2^2$$

Now reading off the equation for $t$ you get $a_1^2+a_2^2=\sqrt 3-2$ and $a_1^2a_2^2=2+\sqrt 3$ and the answer comes out as $5$ as required.

---

You don't need to go back to the equation for $x$ - that is where you got tangled up.

And the moral is: write everything out carefully if you get it wrong first time. It is so easy to have blind spots (I've had several I remember with shame)

Answer (score -1):

\begin{align}
f(x) &= (x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)(x-a_4) \\
&= x^4 +(2−√3) x^2 +2 + √3 \\
f(1)& = 1 + 2 - √3 + 2 - √3 = 5
\end{align}